# Excel-VBA - if new folder added to path, add new line in Sheet with new folder name

Tags: windows, vba, excel, ms-office

I use a macro, which reads folder names from a path and incorporates the folder names into an excel sheet. This is the code:

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("Path")
    i = 13

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders

        Cells(i + 1, 1) = objSubFolder.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next objSubFolder
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I want to know is this: if I add a new folder and thus a new name, is it possible, that my code **inserts** a new row with this new folder name in my excel sheet in column "A"?

Here are two screenshots to clarify my problem:
No.1: [Baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZaQS.png)
No.2: [After adding a new folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1AqW.png)

As you can see, if a write something in the cell next to the entry "AUTOSAR" and add a folder with the name "ABBA"and let the code run again, the text, which was linked to "AUTOSAR", is now next to "ABBA". This is why I need the code to insert a new row, when a new folder is added in the path.

Comment: How does your list in column A relate to the folders? Is there some relationship between the name of the folders and the words in your list?

Comment: The macro reads folder names from a path and writes the names of the folders in column A. This is the relationship. I need to extract a lot of folder names and get them to an excel sheet, which is not the problem. The Problem is described above.

Comment: @Absinte: Dou you have a solution in mind?

Comment: So you want a new row added? Use Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Comment: I think i need to clarify some things. Lets say I start my macro for the first time: The code will read all the folder names from a path and write them in column "A" in an excel sheet. Now assume that the code writes in cell "A14" the text "AUTOSAR" and i write some additional information about "AUTOSAR" in cell "B14". Now I add a new folder to the path, which is named "ABBA" and let the code run again. Now it will write in cell "A14" the text "ABBA" because "ABBA" comes in the alphabet before "AUTOSAR". Problem is, the info in "B14" is meant for "AUTOSAR" and not "ABBA".

Comment: In short, evertime a folder gets added to the path and the macro is activated, a new row needs to be inserted and in this row in column "A" the new value should be incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this

```
   For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders

        Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) = objSubFolder.Name

    Next objSubFolder
```

Comment: Your solution is not working, because everytime i add a new folder and run the code, the code will look for the next empty cell in column "A" and again list all of the names from the path.

Comment: @leticat, Have you test it?